# How to pass multiple get values in a custom MVC .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a .htaccess to handle some PHP MVC requests. The standard format is:

```
domain.com/module/Controller/action
```

But i need to pass GET variables in some cases, for example:

```
domain.com/module/Controller/action/foo/bar
```

I need to receive in PHP the var `foo` with the value `bar`

```
domain.com/module/Controller/action/foo/bar/hello/world
```

The same thing, i need to get the var `foo` with the value `bar` and `hello` with the value `world`

The rule must be the same for a undefined number of vars, like below.

```
domain.com/module/Controller/action/foo/bar/hello/world/[...]/last/var
```

I have always pairs of `var` / `value` after the module, controller and action.

The RewriteRule i am using is below, it detects only the module, controller and action.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3
```

I am not seeing how changes i should do to get the expected behavior. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/foo/([a-zA-Z]+)/hello/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&foo=$4&hello=$5`

Comment: @KristerAndersson, The vars are dynamic, i don't know its names, so i can't use a static rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)((:?/[^/]+/[^/]+)*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&rest=$4
```

will produce following `$_GET` array

```
Array
(
    [module] => module
    [controller] => Controller
    [action] => action
    [rest] => /hello/world
)
```

you can parse `[rest]` using PHP explode method and some array manipulation

Also you don't need `[A-Z]{1}`, it already matches one token (token or character?) so you can replace it with `[A-Z]`

**Update**

In case you don't want to impose the case sensitive URLs then following simplified rule will work.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)((:?/[^/]+/[^/]+)*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&rest=$4 [NC]
```

**Update 2**

the `((:?/[^/]+/[^/]+)*)` is what *grabs* the `/key/value` pairs and can be broken down as

`/` matches a `/`

`[^/]+` matches 1 or more tokens that are not `/`

`(...)*` looks for whatever is between `(` and `)` 0 or as many times as possible.

`:?` converts a `(...)` from capturing group to only *binding group* and doesn't create a variable for it.

so in effect, said part tries to match occurances of `/anyting_that_is_not_slash/anything_that_is_not_slash`, and if found, puts that whole thing in `$4`

Comment: Nice, suggestion, i will try now. The `[A-Z]{1}` is because the controller name must start with a uppercase letter. Is it okay?

Comment: `[A-Z]` will match exactly one capital letter so that's ok.

Comment: Can you please do an update explaining exactly what `(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*` do? Sorry, my regex knowledge is weak yet.

Comment: Many thanks for the update! When i try `domain.com/module/Controller/action/foo/bar/hello/world` the .htaccess is giving only the last pair (hello/world). Do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: I can look into that in a bit but you could also use `RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)(/.+)*$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&rest=$4 [NC]` if you know what your URL's are going to be like (and validate the `rest` in PHP).

Comment: Using the regex of your last comment the things work perfectly! You save me! Many, many thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I've also updated my answer with correct regex. I messed up a capturing gorup ^^